# Expanding Pandas DataFrame based Nested Dictionary Values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, hierarchy

In short, I'm looking to expand the group level view into the individual components of those groups based on a mapping schema I've created.

I have two sets of data. I have transactional data in `df` and a nested dictionary setup for mapping in `nested`.

```
import pandas as pd
nested = {"Group A":{"Component 1 Share": 0.25, "Component 2 Share": 0.25, "Component 3 Share": 0.25, "Component 4 Share": 0.25}, 
      "Group B":{"Component 1 Share": 0.5, "Component 5 Share": 0.5}}
data = {'date': ['2018-12-01', '2018-12-01', '2018-12-02', '2018-12-02', '2018-12-02'],
    'groups':['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group A', 'Group B', 'Group A'],
    'sold': [100, 200, 200, 300, 60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'groups','sold'])
```

My goal is to get it into this format at the component level with the `nested` dictionary. I've simplified both data structures where the real `df` is much larger and the real `nested` dictionary has many more elements of various lengths.

```
goal_data = {'date': ['2018-12-01', '2018-12-01', '2018-12-01', '2018-12-01', 
                  '2018-12-01', '2018-12-01', 
                  '2018-12-02', '2018-12-02', '2018-12-02', '2018-12-02',
                  '2018-12-02', '2018-12-02', 
                  '2018-12-02', '2018-12-02', '2018-12-02', '2018-12-02'],
    'components':["Component 1 Share", "Component 2 Share", "Component 3 Share", "Component 4 Share",
                  "Component 1 Share", "Component 5 Share",
                  "Component 1 Share", "Component 2 Share", "Component 3 Share", "Component 4 Share",
                  "Component 1 Share", "Component 5 Share", 
                  "Component 1 Share", "Component 2 Share", "Component 3 Share", "Component 4 Share"],
    'sold': [25, 25, 25, 25,
             100, 100,
             50, 50, 50, 50, 
             150, 150, 
             15,15,15,15]}
component_df = pd.DataFrame(goal_data, columns=["date", "components", "sold"])
```

I've tried various methods like `map`, `apply`, `lookup`, & `merge` without luck but intuitively know there's a way to expand out the group level data into the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do start with `nested` `dict` , then do `merge` by each group

```
nestdict_f=pd.DataFrame(nested).stack().reset_index()

newdf=pd.concat([y.merge(nestdict_f,left_on='groups',right_on='level_1')for _,y in df.groupby('date')])    

newdf['sold']=newdf['sold']*newdf[0]

newdf=newdf[['date','level_0','sold']].rename(columns={'level_0':'components'})

newdf
         date         components   sold
0  2018-12-01  Component 1 Share   25.0
1  2018-12-01  Component 2 Share   25.0
2  2018-12-01  Component 3 Share   25.0
3  2018-12-01  Component 4 Share   25.0
4  2018-12-01  Component 1 Share  100.0
5  2018-12-01  Component 5 Share  100.0
0  2018-12-02  Component 1 Share   50.0
1  2018-12-02  Component 2 Share   50.0
2  2018-12-02  Component 3 Share   50.0
3  2018-12-02  Component 4 Share   50.0
4  2018-12-02  Component 1 Share   15.0
5  2018-12-02  Component 2 Share   15.0
6  2018-12-02  Component 3 Share   15.0
7  2018-12-02  Component 4 Share   15.0
8  2018-12-02  Component 1 Share  150.0
9  2018-12-02  Component 5 Share  150.0
```

Comment: This did the trick. Make a small change of `nestdf_f` to `nestdict_f` on ln[3], and I'll mark this as the answer!

Comment: @mitchell-reynolds you are right  and update, thanks